# Grammatik in "koste es auch ihr Leben"

Tags: grammar, usage, subjunctive

Aus dem *Spiegel-Magazin*:

> Redakteurin ... traf Vertreter dieser "Generation Islam", interviewte Männer, die voller Zorn sind auf den Westen, die auf ihren Shirts für den "Islamischen Staat" werben, deren Eltern in einer Zwischenwelt gefangen sind, nicht mehr daheim in ihrem Ursprungsland, aber auch nicht angekommen in Deutschland. Diese Unsicherheit gaben sie ihren Kindern mit. Die aber fanden in einer extremen Auslegung des Islam eine Heimat, Sinn, Regeln -- **koste es auch ihr Leben**.

Funktioniert der Ausdrück "koste es auch ihr Leben" -- mit dem Konjunktiv I -- nur mit dem Verb "kosten"? Kann man beispielsweise

> (a) Er möchte hinaus gehen -- sei es draußen kalt.

oder

> (b) Sie will dieses Auto kaufen -- heiße es, dass sie viel Geld ausgeben muss.

sagen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ja, es funktioniert auch mit anderen Verben, allerdings nicht so wie in deinen Beispielen.

Die sog. [V1 Stellung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/V1-Stellung#V1-Stellung_in_Nebens.C3.A4tzen) in Nebensätzen existiert generell auch ohne Konjunktiv I. Damit darin Konjunktiv I angewendet wird, muss der dazugehörige Hauptsatz entweder im Präteritum oder im Konjunktiv I stehen. Außerdem müssen meistens [Modalpartikeln](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modalpartikel) hinzugefügt werden.

Diese Form wird fast ausschließlich im Schriftdeutsch verwendet (oft in der indirekten Rede), im gesprochenen Deutsch werden aber meist andere Nebensatzkonstruktionen herangezogen (außer z. B. bei Redewendungen).

Angepasst könnten deine Beispiele wie folgt aussehen:

> (a) Er werde hinausgehen, sei es auch (noch so) kalt.
>
> (b) Sie wollte dieses Auto kaufen, hieße es doch, dass sie dafür viel Geld ausgeben müsste.

Comment: "Muss der dazugehörige Hauptsatz entweder im Präteritum oder im Konjunktiv I stehen." Heißt das, dass der Hauptsatz **nicht** im Konjunktiv II stehen kann? (Nicht, dass ich deiner Antwort nicht glaube, aber ich wollte mir nur klarmachen.)

Comment: Wenn der Hauptsatz im Konjunktiv II stehen würde, müsste im Nebensatz auch Konjunktiv II angewendet werden. (<-- siehe Beispiel)

Comment: Hmm.. warum dann ist "(a) Er würde hinausgehen, sei es auch (noch so) kalt" korrekt?

Comment: Weil in Beispiel (a) der Konjunktiv I von "er wird hinausgehen" genommen wird und nicht der Konjunktiv II von "er geht hinaus" (vereinfacht ausgedrückt) -- EDIT: ups, hab ich mich doch tatsächlich vertan - werde das Beispiel korrigieren.